# How can I define the number of columns when using text-to-columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to recreate a table from a pdf file. I am able to copy the whole thing, which, when pasted becomes (simplified for this example):

"Col1 Col2 Col3 10 20 30 5 6 7 100 250 350".

When using text-to-column delimited on spaces, Excel makes everything column headers. Is there a way to tell Excel that I want 3 columns, so it "wraps" the following values? Such that output becomes:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 100 | 250 | 350 |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have no problem to directly copy-paste a table from PDF to Excel. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: "Col1 Col2 Col3 10 20 30 5 6 7 100 250 350" This is a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Text to Columns ("T2C") wizard (and its broader, hence parent, Import Wizard) has no way to do that. At all.

You can achieve it via Power Query though, but it would take "a little doing" as in learning more about PQ than just moving columns and re-Typing column data.

However, you can work around it.

Select a cell with something in it. Any such cell. Fire up T2C. Follow the Delimited path to selecting a/several delimiter/s. Make sure the checkbox by `Space` is checked. Exit the wizard immediately (you have no desire to convert whatever cell you selected) once that checkbox is checked.

Copy the material and paste it into the cell you want to have it in. Be sure you pick one with plenty of room to the right of it. If it pastes WITH the double quoting shown in your question, you just have two steps to perform. If it does not have them, then this paste pasted the data into 12 columns, directly.

Select the cell/s. I'll assume just one cell for now, but it follows for a column pasting. Fire up T2C and go the Delimited route, then use `Finish` to complete it. If it was double quoted, this removes the double quotes. Once the double quotes are gone (and you could've just edited them away if preferred), do the T2C again following the Delimited path and you will have your 12 columns.

If you had one cell to T2C, just select columns 4-6 of the output and drag them under the pasting cell and the two columns to its right. Then 7-9, then 10-12.

Aggravating, but done.

If you pasted several cells of data, you can do the same, just with blocks of cells, not rows. If their order was important, insert columns to the left of original columns 4, 7, and 10 placing 1's in the first row, 2's in the second, and 3's in the third, and so on. Move the blocks as described, but include each one's numbered column too, placing it in the column to the left of the "Col1" column. After all are moved, `Sort` the non-"Colx" rows by that numbered column. All the 1's move up, etc., and by not sorting by any other column, you maintain the order in the moved blocks themselves. So now you have the PDF's original table row order.

I used to have this problem, and worse, since a PDF is a program, not a document, and sometimes material in a table is scattered all over the thing and you collect far more than just the table, all unrelated. A horror.

Using Acrobat ("X", not "DC", but perhaps DC has a similar feature though it did not when I got a new computer and uninstalled it for being brain-dead), one can use `Ctrl-Mouse` to draw a rectangle around a portion of the screen and cause it to copy the "picture" except it runs it through its OCR turning it into whatever it can make of it. Since one carefully draws the rectangle to include some white space around the TEXT one is copying but is SUPER CAREFUL not to include stray bits of anything else (carelessness is NOT rewarded!!!), the OCR has never ever failed me in years of using the feature. **(By the way, if that is hard in a circumstance, increase the magnification until it is NOT hard to do. It doesn't mind, and you get no stray bits of anything at the edges.)**

Then Paste into Excel. It always works like a charm for me then. Exact order is maintained and no unrelated material from around the PDF is inserted. The PICTURE you created is precisely what's displayed, not drawn from where the text pictured is stored in the file along with anything in the bounds of that text's start to finish points.

(For me, IRS publication tax tables were always the worst, the living worst. This solved even them. Though... life is like this... nowadays, straight copy/paste often works fine for them. But I KNOW that if I'd never have found this, they never would have raised their game...)

Also, I should mention that every different PDF creator creates them differently, in that the path followed during creation differs and the output file differs. Create the "same" PDF (same source document) via the 2-3-4 ways you can on your computer and compare the output files. Or using whatever PDF editor you might use open a PDF and immediately export it as a PDF from that editor then compare that output file to the one you opened. All that's required for a PDF creator is that the onscreen or printed output look like the original material. This is why direct copy and paste, and often PQ too, do not work so well all the time... there's just too much variability and too many stupidly chosen creation choices that ruin the data integrity.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'll have a look at using OCR.